# Facebook: Removing "&theatre" Mode

Tags: facebook, facebook-photos

On Facebook, I've found that if you remove the `&theatre` from the URL when viewing a picture, it reverts back to the original way of viewing pictures. 
Is there any way I can make the removal permanent?

Answer (score 2):

[Facebook Photo Theater Killer](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/96773)

> Kills the annoying (IMHO) new photo theater on facebook. Instead loads the old photo viewer, as long as facebook keeps it running.

Hope this helps.

Comment: gotta love Greasemonkey

Answer (score 1):

[Social Fixer](http://socialfixer.com/), an extension / user script for Firefox, Opera, Chrome and Safari, can be configured to disable the 'Photo Theater' in Facebook, among other Facebook site fixes and enhancements.