# Black-backgrounded pictures in Facebook. How can I disable it?

Tags: facebook, photos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook: Removing “&theatre” Mode](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/12525/facebook-removing-theatre-mode)

Recently Facebook has changed the way the photos are displayed, and I don't like it. This style has also ruined the tags in my photos. The tagging squares are not pointing the correct areas inside the photos.

I'd like to revert it to the good old way. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to turn it off from Facebook side. But you can either use some script - http://www.sizzledcore.com/2011/02/21/get-old-facebook-photo-viewer-in-firefox-chrome/ or remove the parameter theatre from the end of the URL (https://i.stack.imgur.com/uScRX.jpg) or reload the photo or from the album view open the photo in a new tab (either by right click > open in new tab or middle click)

Comment: +1. Deleting `&theatre` works fine. I'll go with it.